# FP3 Vectors question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

$$\mathbf{a}=a_1\mathbf{i}+a_2\mathbf{j}+a_3\mathbf{k}$$ $$\mathbf{b}=b_1\mathbf{i}+b_2\mathbf{j}+b_3\mathbf{k}$$ $$\mathbf{c}=c_1\mathbf{i}+c_2\mathbf{j}+c_3\mathbf{k}$$

Use appropriate determinants to prove that 
$$(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})+(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{c})=\mathbf{a}\times(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c})$$

My answers for each side don't match up.
Can someone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362139/how-to-prove-the-distributive-property-of-cross-product

Answer (score 1):

Using the determinants as usual, for the $\mathbf{i}$-component of $\mathbf{a}\times(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c})$ you have:
$$
\mathbf{i}\left[a_2(b_3+c_3)-a_3(b_2+c_2) \right]=
$$
$$
\mathbf{i}\left[a_2b_3+a_2c_3-a_3b_2-a_3c_2 \right]=
$$
$$
\mathbf{i}\left[(a_2b_3-a_3b_2)+(a_2c_3-a_3c_2) \right]=
$$
$$
\mathbf{i}\left[(a_2b_3-a_3b_2)\right]+\mathbf{i}\left[(a_2c_3-a_3c_2) \right]
$$
that is the $\mathbf{i}$-component of $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{c}$

And the same for other components.