# Clarification Needed How to prove the distributive property of cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Ok i was going through this question on MSE [How to prove the distributive property of cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362139/how-to-prove-the-distributive-property-of-cross-product)
In A.P.'s answer,Can someone explain me why the sum of areas of triangles formed by **a,b** and **a,c** is equal to area of the bigger triangle formed by **a,b+c** ?
Please tell me only if you have a pure geometrical logic,don't use vector theory.Thanks.

Comment: You don't add the areas of triangles formed by **a,b** and **a,c** directly. You have to add them vectorially.

Comment: But why?Can you explain?..btw dont mind..i'm new to this :-P

Comment: When you take magnitude of the right-hand side, you get $|a \times b + a \times c|$ and not $|a \times b| + |a \times c|$.

Comment: I got it...thanks :-)