# Can you cross two cross products with a cross product?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

If we have three vectors: $n$,$a$, and $b$, and I want to evaluate
$$\frac{(n \times a)\times(n \times b)}{2}$$, can I FOIL this to get:

$$\frac{(n \times n) + (n \times b) + (a \times n) + (a \times b)}{2}$$ = 
$$\frac{(n \times b) + (a \times n) + (a \times b)}{2}$$

Comment: No, you can't do that. The closest thing to a distributive property that cross product obeys is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362139/how-to-prove-the-distributive-property-of-cross-product/1365589)

Comment: See the vector triple product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product

Answer (score 3):

The [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) formula is 
$$a \times (b \times c)=(a\cdot c)b-(a\cdot b)c$$
where you need the parentheses because the cross product is not associative.  If you apply this you get
$$(n \times a)\times(n \times b)=((n\times a)\cdot b)n-((n \times a)\cdot n)b\\
=((n\times a)\cdot b)n$$
because the second dot product is zero.