# Prove if $a \times c = b \times c,$ this implies that $c · a − c · b = ±|c| · |a − b|$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove if $a \times c = b \times c,$ this implies that $c · a − c · b = ±|c| · |a − b|$.

$$\underline{a} \times \underline{c}=\underline{b} \times \underline{c} \quad(*)$$

Consider: $$|\underline{a} \times\underline{c}|^{2}=|\underline{a}|^{2}|\underline{c}|^{2}-(\underline{a} \cdot c)^{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow(\underline{a} \cdot c)^{2}=\left.| a\right|^{2}|c|^{2}-|a \times c|^{2}.$$
And $|b \times c|^{2}=|b|^{2}|c|^{2}-(b \cdot c)^{2}\Rightarrow(\underline{b} \cdot \underline{c})^{2}=|\underline{\underline{b}}|^{2}|\underline{\underline{c}}|^{2}-|\underline{b}\times \underline{c}|^{2}$

$So finally: $
$$(a\cdot c)^2-(b\cdot c)^2 = [|a|^2-|a\times c|^2] - [|b|^2|c|^2-|b\times c|^2]$$

but $$(*) \Rightarrow|\underline{a \times c}|^{2}=|b \times c|^{2}$$ so

$$(a \cdot c)^{2}-(b \cdot c)^{2}= |a|^{2}|c|^2 - |b|^2|c|^2$$

Subtract $2(a\cdot c)(b\cdot c)$ from both sides:
$(a \cdot c)^{2}-(b \cdot c)^{2}-2(a \cdot c)(b\cdot c)=\left|c^{2}||a|^{2}-2(a \cdot c)(b \cdot c)\right|-|b|^{2}|c|^{2}$

$$\Rightarrow((\underline{a} \cdot \underline{c})-(b \cdot c))^{2}=\left.|c|^{2} \underline{a}\right|^{2}-2(\underline{a} \cdot c)(b \cdot \underline{c})-|b|^{2}|c|^{2}$$

If I could simply show that $(a\cdot c)(b \cdot c) = |c|^2(a\cdot b)$ Then I think I can finish the proof from there.

Sorry about the poor formatting.

Comment: Please clean up the rest of the stray \\ \\ \ \\ \\

Comment: $(a-b)\times c=0$ iff $a-b$ and $c$ are linearly dependent.  The claim now follows by Cauchy-Schwarz. --  Alternatively, $$0=\|(a-b)\times c\|^2= \|a-b\|^2\|c\|^2-\langle a-b,c\rangle^2,$$ which is the claim.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I understand it now. (Second method is also pretty slick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross product is distributive:
$(a\times c) = (b \times c) \rightarrow (a-b) \times c = 0$

(See Sidd (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/165113/sidd), How to prove the distributive property of cross product, URL (version: 2015-07-18): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365589)

Then as @Michael Hoppe has suggested in the comments: $(a-b)$ and $c$ are linearly dependent.

Then, take the orthogonal decomposition of a general vector $u \in V$ along $v \in V$

It follows from the properties of the dot product being equal to:

- the length of the projection of u onto v
- multiplied by
- length of v, that:

$u = \frac{u \cdot v}{|v|^2} \cdot v + w$, where $w$ is orthogonal to $v$.

Pythagoras implies that $|u|^2 = |\frac{u \cdot v}{|v|^2} \cdot v|^2 + |w|^2$

Then, similar to the Cauchy-Schwarz equality condition we have if $w=0$ then there is no orthogonal component $\iff$ $u,v$ are parallel vectors, aka linearly dependent.

In this case, rearrange to find $|u\cdot v| = |u||v|$ or $u\cdot v = \pm |u||v|$

Finally, apply this to our question where $(a-b)\cdot c = \pm |a-b|\cdot|c|$

or:

$c\cdot a - c\cdot b = \pm |a-b|\cdot|c| \\ \square $